# One SQL query that will return same member more than once where required

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been tasked with writing a single PL/SQL query that provides an error status where a member does not meet data quality standards. For example, if a member has forename shorter the 3 characters, CASE statement will return that member saying "forename too short". I then need the member to be included in the next CASE statement "forename cannot equal surname" and then a final CASE statement "member is below legal working age".
AS things stand, if member fails first check then they are not included in the others. I need my query to potentially return a member 3 times stating the reason for each return.

```
SELECT 
  member_code,
  CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(forename) < 3 THEN 'Forename less than 3 characters'
    WHEN date_of_birth > TO_DATE('31/01/2008', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Date of birth after 31/01/2008'
    WHEN forename = surname THEN 'Forename is equal to surname'
    ELSE 'No error'
  END AS error_status
FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: "... potentially return a member 3 times" >> what does that mean? What is "**return**"? Functions *return* something; if you need a function, which datatype should it return?  Procedures can *return* result via their OUT parameters. Or did you mean to say **display** (using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE)? Or is it something else?

Comment: @Littlefoot, Op meant if a particular forename fails all 3 condition, It should come up thrice in the result with all 3 different reasons.

Comment: You can return 1 row per user with the 3 columns, 1 per reason, and then UNPIVOT the result set , or use the MODEL clause.

Comment: Are you sure that you want those rules? People do have names shorter than 3 characters and the same first name as last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT member_code,
       error_status
FROM   your_table_name
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT 'Forename less than 3 characters' AS error_status,
                1 AS priority
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  LENGTH(forename) < 3
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Date of birth after 31/01/2008' AS error_status,
                1 AS priority
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  date_of_birth > DATE '2008-01-31'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Forename is equal to surname' AS error_status,
                1 AS priority
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE forename = surname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'No Error' AS error_status,
                2 AS priority
         FROM   DUAL
         ORDER BY priority
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       );
```

In earlier versions, you can use multiple `CASE` expressions and then `UNPIVOT` to convert columns to rows:

```sql
SELECT member_code,
       error_status
FROM   (
  SELECT member_code,
         err1,
         err2,
         err3,
         CASE 
         WHEN err1 IS NULL AND err2 IS NULL AND err3 IS NULL
         THEN 'No Error'
         END AS no_error
  FROM   (
    SELECT member_code,
           CASE WHEN LENGTH(forename) < 3 THEN 'Forename less than 3 characters' END
             AS err1,
           CASE WHEN date_of_birth > DATE '2008-01-31' THEN 'Date of birth after 31/01/2008' END
             AS err2,
           CASE WHEN forename = surname THEN 'Forename is equal to surname' END
             AS err3
    FROM   your_table_name
  )
)
UNPIVOT (error_status FOR type IN (err1, err2, err3, no_error));
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (member_code, forename, surname, date_of_birth) AS
SELECT 1, 'Ng',     'Ng',     DATE '2010-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Thomas', 'Thomas', DATE '2008-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Alice',  'Abbot',  DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| MEMBER_CODE | ERROR_STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Forename less than 3 characters |
| 1 | Date of birth after 31/01/2008 |
| 1 | Forename is equal to surname |
| 2 | Forename is equal to surname |
| 3 | No Error |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QZhsd2FB)

Answer (score 1):

You can list the codes in a CTE and `left join` with it, matching a different condition to each code. When none matches, `'No Error'` can jump in `coalesce()`: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XbzqL_Pn)

```sql
with errors(code,message) as (
   select 1,'Forename less than 3 characters' from dual union all
   select 2,'Date of birth after 31/01/2008' from dual union all
   select 3,'Forename is equal to surname' from dual
)
select a.*, coalesce(e.message,'No Error')
from   my_table a left join errors e on
       (   (e.code=1 and 3>length(a.forename))
        or (e.code=2 and a.date_of_birth>TO_DATE('31/01/2008','DD/MM/YYYY'))
        or (e.code=3 and a.forename=a.surname) );
```

| MEMBER_CODE | FORENAME | SURNAME | DATE_OF_BIRTH | COALESCE(CODE,'NOERROR') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | Hanks | 31-DEC-99 | No Error |
| 2 | Rob | Rob | 28-FEB-99 | Forename is equal to surname |
| 3 | Al | Al | 01-JAN-23 | Forename less than 3 characters |
| 3 | Al | Al | 01-JAN-23 | Date of birth after 31/01/2008 |
| 3 | Al | Al | 01-JAN-23 | Forename is equal to surname |

(tested with 11gR2, 18c, 21c, 23c)